# Bootstrap table header issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Check all checkbox problem in chrome] I have a bootstrap table. Table header does not render properly 
        in chrome  browser. And the table css changes when i perform the 
        append  operation. Please check my code.

```
    <div class="panel-body">
   <table id="tableRelease" data-height="400" data-search="true" 
   data- click-to-select="true">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true">    </th>
             <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">Sequence</th>
             <th data-field="stepName" data-sortable="true">Step Type</th>
           <th data-field="parameter" data-sortable="true">Parameter(s)</th>
          <th data-field="packageNo" data-sortable="true">Package No</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>

            </div>
```

```
   // load function 

  function loaddata() {
     try {
    $(function () {
        $('#tableRelease').bootstrapTable({
        });
    });
  }
  catch (ex)
   { LogEvent("CreateRelease.loaddata", ex.message); }
 }


 // append function
         function updatedata(mydata) {
          $('#tableRelease').bootstrapTable("append", mydata);
        }
```

Check all column checkboxes not working in chrome...
   [image: Header css changing in IE when appending the data to table]

Answer (score 0):

Give width for each columns (Table header and the table body also). Check this example. 
    
http://jsfiddle.net/nithin_dev/0umxqsd7/

Comment: can you share the response of your ajax request.